# Parse multi-line log file with context changing lines in between

Tags: python, parsing

## Problem Statement

I run a program which creates a large plain text log file. In there are a lot
of blocks with numbers that I would like to extract for further analysis.
Unfortunately, there is not much structure in there. At the beginning there is
*one* block with some information about the problem size and the number of
nodes used:

```
Lattice initialized:
  problem size = 16 16 16 32
  layout size = 8 16 16 32
  logical machine size = 1 1 2 4
  subgrid size = 16 16 8 8
  total number of nodes = 8
  total volume = 131072
  subgrid volume = 16384
```

To get those numbers, I would just iterate through every line in the file and
then see whether I could fine the regular expression pattern `total number of nodes = (\d+)` in there. This works.

The program does a simulation which needs to solve multiple systems of linear
equations for a single *update*. There are an arbitrary amount of updates per
log file. Each of them is introduced by a line like this:

```
Doing Update: 29 warm_up_p = 1
```

So far I have just extracted the performance data (more below) for the whole
file, ignoring the update they belong to. I would like to change that now and
have the performance in the context of the update and see whether it is slowing
down.

There are different solvers used, each has a different output:

invcg:

```
QDP:FlopCount:invcg2 Performance/CPU: t=2.577605(s) Flops=19473629184 => 7554.93149027877 Mflops/cpu.
QDP:FlopCount:invcg2 Total performance:  7554.93149027877 Mflops = 7.55493149027877 Gflops = 0.00755493149027877 Tflops
CG_SOLVER: 37 iterations. Rsd = 2.06699506385389e-09 Relative Rsd = 5.77136063168358e-13
CG_SOLVER_TIME: 2.72206 sec
```

minvcg:

```
MInvCG2: 36 iterations
QDP:FlopCount:minvcg Performance/CPU: t=2.998556(s) Flops=21837643776 => 7282.72000789713 Mflops/cpu.
QDP:FlopCount:minvcg Total performance:  7282.72000789713 Mflops = 7.28272000789713 Gflops = 0.00728272000789713 Tflops
```

QPhiX Clover CG:

```
QPHIX_CLOVER_CG_SOLVER: 29 iters,  rsd_sq_final=8.70199859880196e-11
QPHIX_CLOVER_CG_SOLVER: || r || / || b || = 8.70199859880196e-11
QPHIX_CLOVER_CG_SOLVER: Solver Time=0.0646071434020996 (sec)  Performance=239.823066739962 GFLOPS
QPHIX_MDAGM_SOLVER: total time: 0.079926 (sec)
```

QPhiX Clover Multi-Shift:

```
QPHIX_CLOVER_MULTI_SHIFT_CG_MDAGM_SOLVER: Iters=30 Solver Time=0.0672321319580078 (sec)  Performance=253.535273917039 GFLOPS
QPHIX_CLOVER_MULTI_SHIFT_CG_MDAGM_SOLVER: total time: 0.225874 (sec)
```

QPhiX Clover BICGSTAB:

```
QPHIX_CLOVER_BICGSTAB_SOLVER: 8 iters,  rsd_sq_final=6.82060929874834e-09 ||r||/||b|| (acc) = 9.48324202036213e-08
QPHIX_CLOVER_BICGSTAB_SOLVER: Solver Time=0.114965915679932 (sec)  Performance=35.4751782550446 GFLOPS
QPHIX_CLOVER_BICGSTAB_SOLVER: total_iters=17 || r || / || b || = 8.2259136270501e-08
```

The performance in Gflop/s is always on a single line. So I was able to use
regular expressions like this to extract the data:

```
QDP:FlopCount:(\S+) Total performance:  ([\d.]+) Mflops = ([\d.]+) Gflops = ([\d.]+) Tflops
```

I'd also like to have the number of iterations in the solver in the context of
the update number. In the end, I want to analyze things like these *per solver
algorithm*:

- Iterations vs. update number
- Performance vs. update number
- Performance vs. iterations
- Performance vs. Number of nodes

The multiple line blocks for the solvers could be parsed with multi-line
regular expressions, I presume. But since there can be multiple solver blocks
for each update number, I need some parser with a state. I have never used a
proper parsing library, but I feel that this is the point to use one.

What would be a sensible starting point to write a Python (or C++ if libraries
are way better) program to extract the data from this log file?

## pyparsing Attempt

In the meantime I have tried pyparsing which I have heard a couple of times. This is my attempt that actually somewhat works:

```
import argparse
import pprint
import textwrap

from pyparsing import Word, Optional, OneOrMore, Group, ParseException, Suppress, SkipTo, ZeroOrMore, Combine

caps = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
lowers = caps.lower()
digits = "0123456789"


def print_results(results):
    lines = []
    #lines.append(str(type(results)))
    if isinstance(results, str):
        lines.append(results)
    else:
        for key, val in sorted(results.items()):
            lines.append(key)
            lines.append(textwrap.indent(print_results(val), '  '))

    return '\n'.join(lines)



def main(options):
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

    with open(options.logfile) as f:
        content = f.read()

    all_letters = ''.join(sorted(set(content)))

    g_integer = Word(digits)
    g_float = Word(digits + '+-.eE')

    g_subgrid_volume = Suppress('subgrid volume =') + g_integer('subgrid_volume')

    g_invcg = Combine(Suppress('QDP:FlopCount:invcg2 Performance/CPU: t=')
                      + Suppress(g_float)
                      + Suppress('(s) Flops=')
                      + Suppress(g_float)
                      + Suppress(' => ')
                      + Suppress(g_float)
                      + Suppress(' Mflops/cpu.\nQDP:FlopCount:invcg2 Total performance:  ')
                      + Suppress(g_float)
                      + Suppress(' Mflops = ')
                      + g_float('gflops')
                      + Suppress(' Gflops = ')
                      + Suppress(g_float)
                      + Suppress(' Tflops\nCG_SOLVER: ')
                      + g_integer('iterations')
                      + Suppress(' iterations. Rsd = ')
                      + Suppress(g_float)
                      + Suppress(' Relative Rsd = ')
                      + Suppress(g_float)
                      + Suppress('\nCG_SOLVER_TIME: ')
                      + Suppress(g_float)
                      + Suppress(' sec')
                     )

    g_minvcg = Combine(Suppress('MInvCG2: ')
                       + g_integer('iterations')
                       + Suppress(' iterations\nQDP:FlopCount:minvcg Performance/CPU: t=')
                       + Suppress(g_float)
                       + Suppress('(s) Flops=')
                       + Suppress(g_float)
                       + Suppress(' => ')
                       + Suppress(g_float)
                       + Suppress(' Mflops/cpu.\nQDP:FlopCount:minvcg Total performance:  ')
                       + Suppress(g_float)
                       + Suppress(' Mflops = ')
                       + g_float('gflops')
                       + Suppress(' Gflops = ')
                       + Suppress(g_float)
                       + Suppress(' Tflops')
                      )

    g_qphix_clover_cg = Combine(
        'QPHIX_CLOVER_CG_SOLVER: '
        + g_integer('iterations')
        + ' iters,  rsd_sq_final='
        + Suppress(g_float)
        + '\nQPHIX_CLOVER_CG_SOLVER: || r || / || b || = '
        + Suppress(g_float)
        + '\nQPHIX_CLOVER_CG_SOLVER: Solver Time='
        + Suppress(g_float)
        + ' (sec)  Performance='
        + g_float('gflops')
        + ' GFLOPS\nQPHIX_MDAGM_SOLVER: total time: '
        + Suppress(g_float)
        + ' (sec)'
    )

    g_update = Suppress('Doing Update:') + g_integer('update_no')
    g_before_update = SkipTo(g_update)
    g_solver_block = (g_invcg('invcg') | g_minvcg('minvcg') | g_qphix_clover_cg('qphix_clover_cg'))
    g_solver_blocks = Suppress(SkipTo(g_solver_block)) + g_solver_block
    g_update_block = Suppress(g_before_update) + Group(g_update + OneOrMore(g_solver_blocks))('update_block')
    g_logfile = Suppress(SkipTo(g_subgrid_volume)) + g_subgrid_volume + OneOrMore(g_update_block)

    results = g_logfile.parseString(content)

    print(print_results(results))
```

That takes just a few seconds for a small file and gives the desired output:

```
subgrid_volume
  16384
update_block
  qphix_clover_cg
    gflops
      375.885935327638
    iterations
      20
  update_no
    1
```

A typical file has `274480` lines and that took 261 seconds to parse. Not really cool. It is not a real problem because the process generating the data runs for three to six hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're dealing with a huge amount of data and performance is a large concern, my feeling is that there's no reason to get too complicated with this. Split the log file by the update lines

```
update_lines = {}
with open(log_path, 'r') as fh:
  update = None
  for line in fh.readlines():
    if update is None:
      continue
    match = re.match('^Doing Update: (\d+) warm_up_p = (\d+)', line)
    if match:
      update = match.group(0)
      update_lines[update] = []
      continue
    update_lines[update].append(line)
```

then, feed the list of lines for each update through a series of functions that parse for a specific solver

```
for update, lines in update_lines.items():
  invcg_info = parse_invcg(lines)
  minvcg_info = parse_minvcg(lines)

  # etc, etc.
```

If you are bounded by the size of the files/speed, but not *too* bounded, you could chain the parsing into a single function to avoid going over the same lines over and over again. My two cents, but I feel like any sort of EBNF-based parsing is probably overkill.

Comment: That is clever, just splitting it into chunks by the known hierarchy. I think one could even use a regex-split for this.

Comment: That would work, too. There are a few ways you can part out the chunks, which basically exist on an efficiency/stupid simplicity scale, but I think generally if it can be stupid simple, go that way. If you're getting frustrated by the amount of time you have to wait to see your results, then it's worth speeding things up.

Comment: I have now used the line-based approach. Using `collections.defaultdict(list)`, one can save this `update_lines[update] = []`, that is my favorite new module now. Using that approach, I can parse the file and extract the information in 1.1 seconds. Quite an improvement!

Comment: glad I could help! speaking of fun with dictionaries, are you familiar with dict.setdefault()? it's not particularly useful in this context, but it's one of those great little quality of life things (it replaces `bar = my_d.get('foo')
if bar is None:
  bar = []
  my_d['foo'] = bar`

Comment: I think that the defaultdict does the same thing.